# How can I use a custom list method and a custom action in a viewset in DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

From the code below you can see that I use a `modelviewset`, a custom `list` method and a custom action called `get_recent_movies`.

```
class MoviesViewSet(LoginRequiredMixin, ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.SessionAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer

    filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,
                       rest_framework.filters.SearchFilter,
                        rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter)
    filter_class = MovieFilter
    search_fields = {"title", "genre", "country", "language"}
    ordering_fields = ("title", "genre", "country", "language", "release_year", "timestamp")

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Movie.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).select_related()
        return queryset

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        # Check for Datatables and server side processing parameters
        draw = self.request.query_params.get("draw", None)
        start = self.request.query_params.get("start", None)
        length = self.request.query_params.get("length", None)

        if draw and start and length:
            draw = int(draw)
            start = int(start)
            length = int(length)
            queryset = queryset[start:start+length]
            serializer = MovieListSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            result = {"draw": draw,
                      "recordsTotal": total_count,
                      "recordsFiltered": total_count,
                      "data": serializer.data}
            return Response(result)
        else:
            serializer = MovieListSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)


    @action(methods=["get"], detail=False,
            url_path="recent", url_name="recent")
    def get_recent_movies(self, request):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        queryset = queryset.filter(status=1).order_by("-timestamp")[:12]
        serializer = MovieListSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

The reason for the custom `list` method is that I use Datatables and server side proecessing so the data have to be formated the correct way.

I use the `get_recent_movies` to get the last 12 movies a user has seen.

The issue is that the data from `get_recent_movies` need to be formatted for Datatables when displayed in a table. I could repeat the list method in my custom action but I don't want do that.

I am not sure how to pass a queryset from a custom action to the list method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way you could achieve your goal:

```py
class MoviesViewSet(LoginRequiredMixin, ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.SessionAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer

    filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,
                       rest_framework.filters.SearchFilter,
                        rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter)
    filter_class = MovieFilter
    search_fields = {"title", "genre", "country", "language"}
    ordering_fields = ("title", "genre", "country", "language", "release_year", "timestamp")

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Movie.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).select_related()

        if self.action == 'get_recent_movies':
             queryset = queryset.filter(status=1).order_by("-timestamp")[:12]

        return queryset


    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        # Check for Datatables and server side processing parameters
        draw = self.request.query_params.get("draw", None)
        start = self.request.query_params.get("start", None)
        length = self.request.query_params.get("length", None)

        if draw and start and length:
            draw = int(draw)
            start = int(start)
            length = int(length)
            queryset = queryset[start:start+length]
            serializer = MovieListSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            result = {"draw": draw,
                      "recordsTotal": total_count,
                      "recordsFiltered": total_count,
                      "data": serializer.data}
            return Response(result)
        else:
            serializer = MovieListSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)


    @action(methods=["get"], detail=False, url_path="recent", url_name="recent")
    def get_recent_movies(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Pay attention to the `get_queryset` method. This is where you can control what data you are feeding to your custom action.